# How to Write link_to for acts_as_votable nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, acts-as-votable

I am trying to add voting to my site. I have *improvements* that are created and displayed inside of the *projects* show page. I'm trying to allow users to vote on improvements but I am getting an error that I think is related to how I'm linking the like button.

in my `routes.rb` file:

```
  resources :projects do

    resources :improvements do      
        member do
            put "like" => "improvements#upvote"
            put "unlike" => "improvements#downvote"
        end

    end
   end
```

In my view:

```
<%= link_to like_improvement_path(improvement), class: "like", method: :put do %>
```

Rails recommended me to write:

```
<%= link_to project_like_improvement_path(improvement), class: "like", method: :put do %>
```

But this doesn't work. So I tried doing this in my `routes.rb`:

```
  resources :projects do

    resources :improvements

  end

   resources :improvements do       
        member do
            put "like" => "improvements#upvote"
            put "unlike" => "improvements#downvote"
        end
   end
```

Using the original link_to, the voting works, but clicking on the vote button takes me to the improvements show page. I want to stay on the projects page.

Answer (score 0):

If:

```
<%= link_to like_improvement_path(improvement), class: "like", method: :put do %>
```

Works then in the improvements controller's (upvote?) action simply do a:

`redirect_to projects_path`
At the end of whatever else you do model wise.
Change "projects_path" to the correct route for the page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution with your original routes.rb:

```
<%= link_to like_project_improvement_path(improvement.project, improvement), class: "like", method: :put do %>
```

You can write a redirect_to inside the upvote and downvote methods in the improvements controller.